# Is there an Application level OnStop method, rather than just the Activity level?

Tags: android

I want set my current user to not authenticated every time the phone goes to sleep or the app is switched off (i.e. either goes to the desktop or another app), so that they always have to authenticate when the app comes back on again.

I don't want to do this in the `OnStop` or `OnPause` methods in each activity, only when the app isn't currently active.

Ideally there would be an `OnStop` method in the Application base object or some other global context, similar to this:

```
public class MyApp : Application
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }
}
```

but unfortunately this doesn't exist. Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `onDestroy()`

Comment: Where though? It's not available in the Application object

Comment: Well, I have never done something similar, but, maybe, implementing the following would work: `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` -> `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityDestroyed()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there isn't. The solution was to test in an inactivity timer, e.g.:

```
private void InactivityTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _secondsElapsed += 1;
    if (_screenEventReceiver.IsScreenOff || IsApplicationSentToBackground(this.ApplicationContext))
    {
       // do things that you would OnStop here
    }

}

public static bool IsApplicationSentToBackground(Context context) 
{
    try
    {
        var am = (ActivityManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
        var tasks = am.GetRunningTasks(1);

        if (tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            var topActivity = tasks[0].TopActivity;
            if (topActivity.PackageName != context.PackageName)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Errors.Handle(Context, ex);
        throw;
    }

    return false;
}

    private class ScreenEventReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public bool IsScreenOff { get; private set; }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionScreenOff)
            {
                IsScreenOff = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsScreenOff = true;
            }
        }
    }
```